# Sending Variables in Post

Tags: php, html, post

I want to send only one variable via the post method. I have queried the database and have to post $row[id] variable to the page along with the form. To send the user's input we simply do dfs. and the value is send. But, how can i send the variable $row[id] to the file. And also, how would I access it?

Comment: What? A form can post any number of variables (zero or more), each of which will be available in PHP in the `$_POST` array. what you do with it after that is really a separate question.

Comment: No, what I am asking is normally we write like <input type="text" name="xyz"></input> and then we access it as $_POST[xyz]. This way we can send a variable that a user write. But, I want to send something that user has not written but there in my sending file as $row['id']. So, I want to send this variable as well. How can I do that? And also how will I be able to access that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correct, but you could try to use hidden input to store your variable:

```
<input type="hidden" name="whatever_name" value="whatever_value" />
```

You can access it on PHP side the same as any other `$_POST` field.